# python regular expressions example

Tags: python

I created a regular expression to find strings that matches as below.

```
window.location="process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp";
location.href = "http://www.foo.com";
location.href="http://www.foo.com";
window.location = "http://www.foo.com";
window.location.href="http://www.foo.com";
location.replace ("http://www.foo.com");
location.replace( "http://www.foo.com" ) ; 
location.assign ("http://www.foo.com");
window.location= var +"process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp";
window.location.href = path + "login" + ".html";
window.location.href = path + featureId + ".html";
window.location.href = "/" + "online-banking" + ".html";
window.location.href = path + featureName +".html";
window.location.href = link.page;
window.location.href = path + link.page + ".html";'
```

I checked this expression worked  correctly in regular expression testing page.

However, I couldn't get the right result when I executed the program.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

url_reg= re.compile('(location\.(href|assign|replace)|window\.location(\.href|))\s*(=|\()+.*(;|$)')

test = '123123gjh123\
2135115123\
window.location="process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp";\
location.href = "http://www.foo.com";\
location.href="http://www.foo.com";\
window.location = "http://www.foo.com";\
window.location.href="http://www.foo.com";\
location.replace ("http://www.foo.com");\
location.replace( "http://www.foo.com" ) ; \
location.assign ("http://www.foo.com");\
window.location= var +"process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp";\
window.location.href = path + "login" + ".html";\
window.location.href = path + featureId + ".html";\
window.location.href = "/" + "online-banking" + ".html";\
window.location.href = path + featureName +".html";\
window.location.href = link.page;\
window.location.href = path + link.page + ".html";'
print url_reg.findall(test)
```

result :

```
[('window.location', '', '', '=', '')]
```

I want to get result value as below.

```
['window.location="process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp"','location.href = "http://www.foo.com"','window.location = "http://www.foo.com"','window.location.href="http://www.foo.com"',..]
```

please give me some advice.

Comment: ``findall`` doesn't do any kind of replacing, it just finds matches to your regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it your purpos? I just added `r''` and outter parentheis.

```
import re

url_reg= re.compile(r'((location\.(href|assign|replace)|window\.location(\.href)?)\s*(=|\()+.*(;|$))')
test = 'blahblah...'
print map(lambda x: x[0], url_reg.findall(test))
```

`['window.location="process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp";location.href =    "http://www.foo.com";location.href="http://www.foo.com";window.location = "http://www.foo.com";window.location.href="http://www.foo.com";location.replace ("http://www.foo.com");location.replace( "http://www.foo.com" ) ; location.assign ("http://www.foo.com");window.location= var +"process.php?file=Generics/index.nsp";window.location.href = path + "login" + ".html";window.location.href = path + featureId + ".html";window.location.href = "/" + "online-banking" + ".html";window.location.href = path + featureName +".html";window.location.href = link.page;window.location.href = path + link.page + ".html";']`